# Jakson IllegalArgumentException: Can not handle managed/back reference

Tags: java, web-services, jackson, spring-rest

**CONTEXT:**

I have 2 webapps:

- front (spring mvc)
- webservice (spring rest)

both communicate by webservice. I'm trying to generate an objet (CounterDTO) in webservice webapp from json like this :

> ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
>   mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES,
>   false); CounterDTO counterDTO =
>   mapper.readValue(json.get(objName).toString(), CounterDTO.class);

**ERROR:**

When I try to build an objet with a json, I have this error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not handle managed/back
>   reference 'entreprise-agency': back reference type (java.util.Set) not
>   compatible with managed type (com.mypackage.Agency)

JSON sent:

> {"id":null,"code":"SKYUE586","name":"name 1"}

I have 3 entities like this :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "AGENCY")
public class Agency {
    ...
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_Entreprise")
    @JsonManagedReference(value = "entreprise-agency")
    private Entreprise entreprise;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "agency", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JsonBackReference(value = "agency-counter")
    private Set<Counter> counters = new HashSet<Counter>();
   ...
}
```

.

```
Entity
@Table(name = "COUNTER")
public class Counter {
    ...
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_Agence")
    // @JsonBackReference
    @JsonManagedReference(value = "agency-counter")
    private Agency agency;
    ...
}
```

.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ENTREPRISE")
public class Entreprise {
    ...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "entreprise", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JsonBackReference(value = "entreprise-agency")
    private Set<Agency> agencies = new HashSet<Agency>();
   ...
}
```

and DTO

```
public class CounterDTO {
    private Integer id;
    private String code;
    private String name;
    ...
}
```

**QUESTION:**

How can I properly handle managed/back jackson reference ?

I've also tried to use this tag on my entities

> @JsonIdentityInfo(generator =
>   ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I've resolved issue by using

[Gson library](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-java-object-to-from-json-format-gson-api/)

Instead of ObjectMapper